Azure SQL trying to verify against incorrect tenant when signing into SSMS
I'm accessing an Azure SQL database in SSMS. I enter the servername, username and password.
SSMS then asks me to sign in to Azure, to add the IP to the database firewall.
I click signin, select my Azure AD account that I always use, but now get the following error:

In Azure, I have set my default tenant to the correct one, so I don't know why it's defaulting to a different tenant.
Appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this. Thanks


The selected user account doesn't exist in the tenant and cannot access the application in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.

The above error occurs when the user account you're trying to sign in with doesn't exist in the Azure Active Directory (AAD) tenant associated with the Azure SQL Database, or it hasn't been properly configured to access the application (in this case, SSMS) within that tenant.
Follow the instructions below to resolve the error:

Ensure that the user account you're using to sign in does indeed exist in the correct Azure AD tenant. Double-check the spelling of the username and verify that it is associated with the correct tenant.

Ensure that the user account has the necessary permissions to access the Azure SQL Database.

If the user account is from a different tenant, or if it's an external user, it needs to be added to the Azure AD tenant associated with the Azure SQL Database. This can be done by an administrator of that tenant by inviting the user as a guest user.

Clear any cached credentials related to the user account in SSMS or in Windows Credential Manager. This ensures that SSMS attempts to authenticate the user account again from scratch.


Alternatively, if you want to add an IP address, you can do so from the Azure portal itself without logging in to AD in SSMS as follows:

Copy the IP address shown in the popup as shown below:



Go to the Networking tab of the SQL server in the Azure portal, click on Add a firewall rule, add the IP address with a Rule name, and click Save, as shown below:



The IP will be added to the SQL server. Cancel the popup, which is showing the IP address mentioned above, and try to connect to the SQL database. It should connect successfully, as shown below:


